# (Android) SQL randomly retrieve a specific row from a query based on the number of times the row has been previously chosen

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, do-while

So i have an android app with a preloaded database in the assets file using *SQLiteAssetHelper*. I have code that makes a query on the database based on a list the user creates by selecting certain buttons. After the list is finished it is made into a query which returns dozens of rows that apply, and the code I have right now randomly selects from the set returned by the query.

This code here:

`randyInt = CursorQuery.getCount();
 CursorQuery.moveToPosition(randy.nextInt(randyInt));
 String row = CursorQuery.getString(0);
 return row;`

What I am trying to make happen is that whenever a row is chosen from the query, it gets a plus 1 added to that specific row (maybe by *rowid* or something). That will happen after the row has been selected. Then, if second query with the same qualifications (list of choices selected by the user) is sent to the database and chooses that same group of rows, it sees that the row chosen before has been selected once, (by the plus 1 that was added or what ever) and selects another row in the query that has been chosen less number of times (in this case 0 times).

So ideally i want a **do while loop** that re-selects one of the rows in the query and chooses the one that has the smallest integer attached to it- the integer being the amount of times that row has already been selected- so that the user will not receive the same result unless all of them have been shown at least once.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds overly complicated, but you need some way of saving the selected choices by the user ( hashing them maybe? ) and then storing that hash with the id of the row that was selected in another table and the number of times that row was selected for that particular query. ( or in memory if you don't need to persist it between executions of the app ).  then either do a join on the table created and sort by asc (, or compare the results with your in-memory cache)..

maybe a table like

```
query_hash | row_id | chosen
----------------------------
ABCD123    |   1    |  2 
....
```

you need a left join so all your main data rows come even if they haven't been selected yet in your "popularity" table.

you also only want to make your query hash out of the options the user chose.

Comment: I know right. I was also considering looking into foreign keys, and have the query also check into the foreign key aspect of the selected row, look at the number, and then modify it there from the code.

Comment: I think the main problem is that not only is the database pretty big, like dozens of tables with about 4 hundred in each, but that there are multiple queries that could return the same row and i needed to track them across the board and not just through one kind of query

Comment: are the queries that return the same results "truly" different or just made in different order but with the same filters and where clauses?  if they are truly different that complicates it greatly..

Comment: They are in fact different, and by that i mean you can receive a different row result with the same where clause but it will be the same thing in the database. So if the user did a search for "family" and then "sibling" and they had 3 brothers and 3 sisters, there would be 6 rows that have all the same fields but the last one, the important one. I don't completely understand foreign keys but would it be possible to still have my structure i just explained, but have all the different rows address the foreign key and then that foreign key can be regulated with the counter. does that make sense?

Comment: looks like we'd need to see your data model to full understand this, also looks like the queries would have to be tracked per user - per query which could become a large amount of data to keep around...